# Code keeps returning the same random numbers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This WP8 quiz app (questions ommited for obvious reasons) keeps repeating the questions as if it's generating the same random numbers over and over. There's a list creation function that shuffles the questions and the generator itself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace GamingQuiz
{
    public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public GamePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ques();
           // PotterGay();

        }
        int MyNumber = 0;
        question[] q = new question[101];
        public void ques()
        {
        //questions are here e.g. q[0]=new question("question","a1","a2","a3","a4",correctanswer)



        }
     // int[] murica = new int[101];
     // int MyNumber = 0;   
        List<int> murica = new List<int>(); 
        public void PotterGay()
        { 
            int hue = 0;
            Random a = new Random(100);

            while (hue<100){
         MyNumber = a.Next(0,100);
            if (!murica.Contains(MyNumber))
            {
                murica.Add(MyNumber);
                hue++; 
            }



            }
        }

        int vCorect = 0;

        public void end()
        {
            intrebare.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            vd.Text = "DICKY DICKY";
            var1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            var2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            var3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            var4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }

        int j = 0;
        int fatista = 0;
        public void right()
        {
            fatista = murica[j];
          //  Random asdf = new Random();
          ///  j = asdf.Next(100);
            intrebare.Text = q[fatista].quest;
            var1.Content = q[fatista].v1;
            var2.Content = q[fatista].v2;
            var3.Content = q[fatista].v3;
            var4.Content = q[fatista].v4;
            vCorect = q[fatista].gj;
            j++;

        }


        public void start_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            PotterGay();
           right();
            start.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
        int scor = 0;
        int baba = 0;
        private void var_tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                switch ((string)((Button)sender).Name)
                {
                    case "var1":
                        if (vCorect == 1)
                        {
                            scor++;
                            vd.Text = "Correct!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scor--;
                            vd.Text = "Wrong!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "var2":
                        if (vCorect == 2)
                        {
                            scor++;
                            vd.Text = "Correct!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scor--;
                            vd.Text = "Wrong!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "var3":
                        if (vCorect == 3)
                        {
                            scor++;
                            vd.Text = "Correct!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scor--;
                            vd.Text = "Wrong!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "var4":
                        if (vCorect == 4)
                        {
                            scor++;
                            vd.Text = "Correct!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            scor--;
                            vd.Text = "Wrong!";
                            baba++;
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
            if (baba < 101)
            {
                right();
                puncte.Text = Convert.ToString(scor);
            }
            else
            {

                murica.Clear();
                end();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is getting downvotes because you've posted a bunch of code with little explanation and just expect people to read through the whole thing. I also don't see an actual question. Clearly, you would like to solve the problem mentioned in the title, but you don't really phrase a question anywhere in the body.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
Random a = new Random(100);
```

The 100 in there is what is known as the SEED. Randoms which have the same seed will always give the same permutations of numbers.

You'll either want the default

```
Random a = new Random();
```

or a seed which is 'random'

```
Random a = new Random(DateTime.Now.Miliseconds);
```

To quote the actual [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes
>   each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.
>
> If your application requires different random number sequences, invoke
>   this constructor repeatedly with different seed values. One way to
>   produce a unique seed value is to make it time-dependent.

Comment: There is no reason to do the latter over the former; you're doing the same conceptual operation with a tad less entropy than would be there by default.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I kept it there for completeness' sake to explain the concept of 'seed'

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `new Random` once and keep re-using the Random Number Generator.  If you keep newing it up with the same seed `100`, then the sequence of numbers you get will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `100` in the call to generate the RNG is called a seed and by specifying it, you will get a known series of pseudo-random numbers.

Secondly, remove the `Random a = new Random(100);` line out of the `PotterGay()` method and make it a class member instead (`private Random a = new Random();`). You should only need one RNG for this. Fast, repeated calls to the `PotterGay()` method could wind up generating the same random sequence, even without the specified seed.

Comment: That's a good point, except I think he's only calling PotterGay once each time the application runs. Unless I'm totally misinterpreting the purpose of start_Tap.

Comment: Tap is the new MouseClick, sufficiently slow and user-random to make the second part of your answer unnecessary.